# How can I use combobox and textbox in login form

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I'm trying to develope an interface to the company I'm training with. And in the login form I want the user to select the department he/she works in then put the department code which I have it, then it should open another form which they can choose their name and type the passowrd. if the user select IT department then the employees in the IT department should appear only. (I'm using Access database) Hope someone could help me!!

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace IT_Department_Interface
{
    public partial class frm_login : Form
    {

       private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public frm_login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Database1New.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from Info where geha_name='" + com_dept.Text + "' and geha_code= '" + txt_dept.Text + "'" ;
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: talking is cheap. show us some code :P

Comment: I would strongly suggest you google populating one combobox with a selection from another.